# Git hard reset is not reverting local files

Tags: git, git-reset

I have a feature branch, let's call it feature/JIRA-1000.
On this branch I had a commit with a message that we can call "It works."

After this, I refactored the code significantly and commited the changes as "Refactoring."
However, then I realized, I should have made the changes as part of another task (JIRA 2000), on a separate branch. So from JIRA, I created a new branch feature/JIRA-2000, based on feature/JIRA-1000. That new branch thus contained both the "It works" and the "Refactoring" commit.

Then I wanted to remove the "Refactoring" commit from the feature/JIRA-1000 branch. So in Gitkraken, I right-clicked the "It works" committ and selected "Reset -> hard".
I have also tried it from Git Bash:

```
$ git checkout feature/JIRA-1000
Already on 'feature/JIRA-1000'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature/JIRA-1000'.

$ git reset --hard f9ef772b188ae359a77804b63a79aa542fd44e6b
HEAD is now at f9ef772 SERDOC-1000 It works

$ git push -f
Everything up-to-date
```

But now comes the catch: My local files are not changed.

What am I doing wrong?

Gitkraken might have messed something up as I believe I had some unstaged changes when I first ran the command and I can see a commit entry that says:

```
Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/feature/JIRA-1000' into feature/JIRA-1000
```

at the top of my branch history. But anyway, JIRA-2000 is the way it should be now. I just can't revert JIRA-1000 back to the way I want it to be.

Edit:
I just accidentally repeated the hard reset on the JIRA-2000 branch (the new branch I didn't want to reset). The hard reset in this case *did* reset my local changes.
(Thankfully, I was able to undo this by hard resetting again to the "Refactoring" commit).
So maybe my JIRA-1000 branch is somehow broken?

Comment: Did you reset hard to "It works", or to "Refactoring"? I'm there latter case, the behavior was expected.

Comment: I reset to "It works", see the console output above.

Comment: Are you accepting command-line solutions, or does it have to be GUI only?

Comment: Command-line solutions are fine.

Comment: Also, that single command doesn't show much. Can you show a sequence of commands showing how you select the branch, etc?

Comment: I have updated my question. Better now?

Comment: You actually did everything right. Are you sure your IDE is using the correct repository? Perhaps you have that same repository in two different folders for what reason soever and your IDE is using the repository you didn't do those commands.
Can you also check the changes in code from the terminal to make sure if it didn't really change?

Comment: Did you push your changes? Because it looks like the remote version of Jira1000 was not reverted and then git kraken automatically fast forwarded you right back to where you were. Try `git push -f` immediately after the reset.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It worked fine on the JIRA-2000 branch somehow. Tried the same again on the JIRA-1000 branch, including the forced push, and nothing happened (updated the question as well).

Comment: Never mind. It seems like @EdsonHoracioJunior was right. My IDE did not update. Sorry. So strange that it worked just fine when I was on the other branch.

Comment: @Edson. Please consider posting a full answer. This is something that may be valuable to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually did everything right.

Are you sure your IDE is using the correct repository? Perhaps you have that same repository in two different folders for what reason soever and your IDE is using the repository you didn't do those commands.

Can you also check the changes in code from the terminal to make sure if it didn't really change?

Comment: Indeed it was my mistake. For some reason, Visual Studio did not ask me to reload the solution and it still showed all files as intact. I blindly trusted Visual Studio.